# PHP and MySQL encrypting passwords with a Caesar shift?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I have a PHP login system where I check the username that the user inputted and cross check it with every username in my database. If there is a match it looks at the password and if there is a match again it will grant the user access to their profile. If not they will be redirected to the login screen. I currently store passwords as what they actually are, not encrypted or anything. I was wondering if it is possible to get the password the user inputs when signing up, use an algorithm I will programme such as replace each letter with its corresponding number(a bit more complicated than that obviously). I would then store the password as the output and when reading it in from the database it would be decrypted. Is this safe, if i make my own algorithm or can someone easily look at my code and decipher it?

Comment: This is a **REALLY** bad idea. Use the `password_hash()` function PHP provides.

Comment: And that's an understatement

Comment: You should never ever encrypt passwords. Always hash them, that way even if someone knows the way you've hashed the password, they can't find it.

Comment: If you believe that your encryption-fu is superior to that of the average hacker; but better by far to use a hashing algorithm that has been peer reviewed and affirmed by professional security experts

Comment: Oh just to be complete `password_hash()` comes with `password_verify()`

Comment: 1) Don't ever encrypt passwords, hash them. 2) Don't ever write your own hashing algorithm, unless you are a secret maths genius. And even then, get it very solidly peer reviewed. 3) Use PHP's built-in `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions. 4) Good job recognising that storing passwords in plaintext is a bad idea.

Comment: https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016 , particularly the section about migrating legacy hashes

Comment: can you explain why

Comment: @jack:  http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/

Comment: Why? Because you don't know how good your hashing technique is; if you can't break it, it doesn't mean that joe nasty the darkside hacker can't break it inside 5 seconds

Comment: @jack https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/1998/1015.html#cipherdesign

Answer (score 4):

Do *not* store encrypted or (shudder) plain text passwords.

If you need to store a password value, store the return from a cryptographic hash function.  There's no need to "roll your own" cryptographic hash algorithm. (The strength of a cryptographic algorithm is *not* produced by keeping the algorithm "secret".)

Cryptographic hash algorithms are the workhorse of modern security.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

When you need to test a password (by comparing a submitted password to a stored password value), just run the submitted password (to be tested) through the same cryptographic hash function, and take the return from that and compare to the stored hash value.  If the hash values match, then there is an extremely high probability that the plaintext passwords match. If the hashes don't match, then you are guaranteed that the passwords don't match.

---

To directly address the specific questions you asked:

Q: Is [my proposed implementation] safe?

A: The short answer is no, it's not safe. The first part of my answer describes a better approach to handling password tokens for authentication.

Q: If i make my own algorithm or can someone easily look at my code and decipher it?

A: The strength of a cryptographic algorithm is not found in keeping the code "secret".

Comment: To add to this: Use a specialized password hashing algorithm not a fast general purpose cryptographic hash function. SHA256 is a bad choice. Bcrypt/Argon2i are good choices. `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` give you bcrypt.

Comment: "Why Passwords Should Be Hashed": http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/  and  "How to safely store password" using PHP:   https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#php

Comment: It's not clear to me why this answer received a downvote. (My suspicion is that the downvote was awared by the owner of another answer, which I didn't downvote, but where I did comment that MD5 was not a suitable hashing algorithm for password hash.) If that's not the case, if the downvote was from someone else, and if there is some way in which this answer could be/should be improved, then by all means leave a comment, to alert future readers.